# probability that the difference of two values of a normal is in a given range

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I am dealing with the following problem: from a sample of $n$ heights of people (with normal distribution) I choose $m$ pairs of people and I want to know the probability that at least $k$ (with $k < m$) have a height difference of $x$ centimeters.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can guide me in solving this calculation.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Consider taking a variable Xij Bernoulli that is 1 when the pair i, j has a difference of 5 cm | Xj-Xi |> 5, and then take a variable X that is the sum of all the pairs i, j, and calculate how much it should be worth the probability that the expectation of X is greater than 3.
With this plan I am having trouble putting it into equations and I am also confused by the fact that I would have to choose 5 pairs at random.
I hope I have explained myself well